# This site can’t be reached

Tags: marklogic

Does anyone know's why I'm getting a site can't be reach when I access my virtual machine at 192.168.56.101:8001 in my browser to configure a single host or the first host in a cluster.

Actually I can access my virtualbox via ssh and showing the installation process hereunder:

[root@rhel7 /]# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

always madvise [never]

[root@rhel7 /]# grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo

Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7998/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7998/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7999/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7999/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8001/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8001/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8002/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8002/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8003/tcp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8003/udp --permanent

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd  --reload

success

[root@rhel7 ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all

public (default, active)

interfaces: enp0s3

sources:

services: dhcpv6-client ssh

ports: 7999/tcp 7998/tcp 8002/tcp 8003/tcp 8002/udp 7999/udp 8000/udp 8001/udp     8000/tcp 8003/udp 8001/tcp 7998/udp

masquerade: no

forward-ports:

icmp-blocks:

rich rules:

[root@rhel7 ~]# rpm -i MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-5.8.x86_64.rpm

[root@rhel7 ~]# cd /etc/init.d

[root@rhel7 init.d]# ls

functions  MarkLogic  netconsole  network  README  rhnsd

[root@rhel7 init.d]# /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start

Starting MarkLogic:                                        [  OK  ]

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall service to make sure that is the culprit?

Comment: Not sure it will help your situation, but here's a blog post those who would like to try [MarkLogic on Docker](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/building-a-marklogic-docker-container).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using those local vm's for experimental or development purposes, I recommend looking at Vagrant to create and manage them. I put together a Vagrantfile and scripts to ramp up a complete ML cluster real easily:

https://github.com/grtjn/mlvagrant

HTH!

Comment: Not experimental.  Simulating installation before working on a physical server.

Comment: Right. In that case you probably want an identical setup, and mimic exact steps. You might find looking at the mlvagrant bootstrap scripts useful though. Feel free to nitpick what looks useful to you.